# Celery Flower missing Prometheus metrics

Tags: celery, prometheus, flower

Flower metrics not showing all the metrics in the endpoint `localhost:5555/metrics` such as **flower_worker_number_of_currently_executing_tasks, flower_worker_online"** these metrics are important to be exported to the Prometheus and Grafana to monitoring the status for the celery workers and number of tasks available as the below metrics file

```
# HELP python_gc_objects_collected_total Objects collected during gc
# TYPE python_gc_objects_collected_total counter
python_gc_objects_collected_total{generation="0"} 737488.0
python_gc_objects_collected_total{generation="1"} 94676.0
python_gc_objects_collected_total{generation="2"} 3714.0
# HELP python_gc_objects_uncollectable_total Uncollectable object found during GC
# TYPE python_gc_objects_uncollectable_total counter
python_gc_objects_uncollectable_total{generation="0"} 0.0
python_gc_objects_uncollectable_total{generation="1"} 0.0
python_gc_objects_uncollectable_total{generation="2"} 0.0
# HELP python_gc_collections_total Number of times this generation was collected
# TYPE python_gc_collections_total counter
python_gc_collections_total{generation="0"} 1450.0
python_gc_collections_total{generation="1"} 131.0
python_gc_collections_total{generation="2"} 5.0
# HELP python_info Python platform information
# TYPE python_info gauge
python_info{implementation="CPython",major="3",minor="7",patchlevel="10",version="3.7.10"} 1.0
# HELP process_virtual_memory_bytes Virtual memory size in bytes.
# TYPE process_virtual_memory_bytes gauge
process_virtual_memory_bytes 3.641409536e+09
# HELP process_resident_memory_bytes Resident memory size in bytes.
# TYPE process_resident_memory_bytes gauge
process_resident_memory_bytes 1.35716864e+08
# HELP process_start_time_seconds Start time of the process since unix epoch in seconds.
# TYPE process_start_time_seconds gauge
process_start_time_seconds 1.64777858352e+09
# HELP process_cpu_seconds_total Total user and system CPU time spent in seconds.
# TYPE process_cpu_seconds_total counter
process_cpu_seconds_total 298.32000000000005
# HELP process_open_fds Number of open file descriptors.
# TYPE process_open_fds gauge
process_open_fds 25.0
# HELP process_max_fds Maximum number of open file descriptors.
# TYPE process_max_fds gauge
process_max_fds 1.048576e+06
# HELP flower_events_total Number of events
# TYPE flower_events_total counter
# HELP flower_task_runtime_seconds Task runtime
# TYPE flower_task_runtime_seconds histogram
```

Comment: Your metrics don't include **any** measurements let alone the 2 you want. It appears that Flower provides all [metrics](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prometheus-integration.html#available-metrics) by default, I suspect your configuration is incorrect.

Comment: ... or you're not generating any measurements.

Comment: Hi, make sure you are running the flower==1.0.0, these two metrics are available from this specific version.